# Does the isalpha() method in Python identify all non-alpha characters?

Tags: python, regex, encoding, utf-8, isalpha

I have a file called `messages.txt` which consists of many sentences separated by line. I am attempt to exclude the lines that contain non-alpha characters (I only want those that include characters from A-Z.

```
import re
import string

lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('messages.txt', encoding='utf-8')]

cleaned_lines = [s.replace("!", "").replace(".", "").replace("?", "").replace(",", "") for s in lines]

output_lines = []

for line in cleaned_lines:
  if line.replace(' ', '').isalpha() == True:
    output_lines.append(re.sub(r'\W+', '', line.lower()))

chars = sorted(set(('').join(output_lines)))
print(chars)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ª', 'â', 'ã', 'å', 'ð', 'ÿ', 'œ', 'š', 'ž', 'ƒ', 'ˆ']
```

As it can be seen, it seems as if the isalpha() method is not excluding the strange

```
'â', 'ã', 'å', 'ð', 'ÿ'
```

characters. I have a feeling that this may be due to the encoding that the file is being read in, however, I would assume that the isalpha method in conjunction with the pattern RegEx should be able to filter out these characters.

Is this intentional? If so, what methods can be used to remove these strange characters?

Comment: It's always a good idea to look at official documentation, [Python isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) clearly mentions it returns `True` for non-empty strings that contain the character that are defined as letter in `utf`

Comment: You could use `isascii()` to filter out strings with non-ascii characters?

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. Based on the documentation, that looks correct! It seems that the correct solution in my case will be to use Iain Shelvington's suggestion and perhaps check for `isascii()` and `isalpha()` in conjunction, while still maintaining the utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my local testing using a UTF-8 encoded Python script, `isalpha()` was returning false for inputs containing characters with accents:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
inp1 = "Hello"
inp2 = "Hållo"
print(inp1.isalpha())  # True
print(inp2.isalpha())  # False
```

In any case, if you want to filter off any line containing a non ASCII alphanumeric character, then just use `re.search` in your initial list comprehension:

```py
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('messages.txt', encoding='utf-8') if not re.search(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]', line)]
```

Comment: Thank you. In my testing, I find a difference. `inp2` returns True. I believe this is because of the `utf-8` encoding in which I am retrieving the file.

Comment: Did you declare your Python script to be using UTF-8?

Comment: Ah, yes, I believe I am. However, my text editor may not support this syntax. Thus, I am receiving a different result. Upon testing it in a different text editor, I get the same result as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file encoded as UTF-8 with:

```
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('messages.txt', encoding='utf-8')]
```

The data in `lines` is Unicode strings.  Depending on the OS/Editor used, the accented characters can be "composed" (using a single codepoint for some accented letters) or "decomposed" (using two codepoints, a letter and a combining accent).

You can force the form that works for you:

```py
import unicodedata as ud
inp = "Hello",ud.normalize('NFC',"Hållo"),ud.normalize('NFD',"Hållo")
for i in inp:
    print(i,ascii(i),i.isalpha(),i.isascii())
```

Output.  Notice the `ascii()` function shows the accended `a` as a single code point `\xe5` or the pair `a\u030a`:

```
Hello 'Hello' True True
Hållo 'H\xe5llo' True False
Hållo 'Ha\u030allo' False False
```

To find only ASCII letters, test with both `isalpha()` and `isascii()`.